# Calling RDS data service executeStatement throws "Parameter X has value with no field set"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Not sure if I clearly understood how to provide parameter values when executing `rds.executeStatement` command.

When I execute the below code I get this error thrown -

```json
{
  "errorType": "BadRequestException",
  "errorMessage": "Parameter \"userId\" has value with no field set",
  "code": "BadRequestException",
  "message": "Parameter \"userId\" has value with no field set"
}
```

Here is my code, How am I supposed to provide the userId and givenName values to the parameters array here.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService({
    apiVersion: '2018-08-01'
});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    var userId;
    var givenName;

    var params = {
        secretArn: 'secretArn',
        resourceArn: 'resourceArn',
        database: 'db',
        parameters: [{
                name: "userId",
                value: {
                    "stringValue": userId
                }
            },
            {
                name: "givenName",
                value: {
                    "stringValue": givenName
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    event.Records.forEach(function(record) {

        if (record.eventName == 'INSERT') {
            userId = record.dynamodb.NewImage.pk.S;
            givenName = record.dynamodb.NewImage.sk.S;
            params.sql = `INSERT INTO Users (UserId, GivenName) VALUES(:userId, :givenName);`
        }


    });
    await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
    console.log(params.parameters[0].value);
    return 'done';
};
```

UPDATE March 13th
Attaching the cloudwatch logs printing out userId and givenName -

[image]

UPDATE March 16th - Function Updates

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService({ apiVersion: '2018-08-01' });

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
var userId;
var givenName;
var count = 0;

var params = {
    secretArn: 'secretArn',
    resourceArn: 'resourceArn',
    database: 'bol_db',
    parameters: [{
            name: "userId",
            value: {
                "stringValue": userId
            }
        },
        {
            name: "givenName",
            value: {
                "stringValue": givenName
            }
        }
    ]
};

const promises = event.Records.map(async function(record) {
    count++;
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (record.eventName == 'INSERT') {
        userId = record.dynamodb.NewImage.pk.S;
        givenName = record.dynamodb.NewImage.sk.S;
        console.log('userId - ' + userId);
        console.log('givenName - ' + givenName);
        console.log('Params -'+params.parameters);
        params.sql = "INSERT INTO Users (UserId, GivenName) VALUES(:userId, :givenName);"
        let result = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
        console.log('Result -' + result);
    }
});

await Promise.all(promises);
console.log(count);
return 'done';
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `event.Records`? Can you do a `console.log` and then share the output please?

Comment: It seems that either `record.dynamodb.NewImage.pk.S;` is empty / undefined or `event.Records` is undefined or somehow, `userId` is not being set.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I have attached the cloudwatch logs printing the values of userId and givenName. The error happens with the rds.executestatement at the end. If I comment that line I get no errors.

Comment: Has nobody encountered this issue before? I have been working around this for sometime, still haven't found an answer. There is not much about it on the internet as well. I have updated my function a lot since, still not able to figure out the issue. Adding the update to the original post.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, Paramater userId has value with no field set. Someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're setting `"stringValue": userId` before `userId` has a value. In JavaScript you can't assign `userId` later and expect it to be propagated to all places that you used it before.

You should try with `var params = {...}` inside the `.map` function or, alternatively, inside the `.map` function you can loop through the parameter list and if you find the correct one, assign the value then.